# Seeking file representing extents of coordinates systems and their wkid?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm looking for a file that represents the major coordinate systems throughout the world, and the extent that they cover.

Ideally they'll also have the wkid as an attribute.

Something like the shapefile found here of UTM zones, but with wkid's
http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/grids/universal_grid_system.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [EPSG polygon shapefiles](http://www.epsg.org/polygons/main.html).

Alternatively, download the [Access database version](http://www.epsg.org/) and build the envelope / rectangular extents from the area table, then a join with the coordinate reference system table to pick up the WKIDs.

Please read the notes connected with the data. These extents and polygons are not meant to be that accurate, but rather a way to rule out non-applicable coordinate reference systems or other coordinate operations.

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.